# Mozilla WebExtensions contextMenus.create not working

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to develop a WebExtension with a contextMenu for FireFox. Currently I only have two files and no real functionality. The problem is it doesn't seem to work even with example code from Mozilla Developer Network - so I'm assuming it's in the manifest, but I can't seem to find the issue.

This is my `manifest.json` file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "FullWindow",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "Test plugin.",

  "permissions": ["contextMenus"],

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["fullwindow.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my `fullwindow.js` file:

```
console.log("Plugin loaded!");

browser.contextMenus.create({
  id: "radio-green",
  type: "radio",
  title: "Make it green",
  contexts: ["all"],
  checked: false
}, onCreated);

function onCreated() {
  if (browser.runtime.lastError) {
    console.log("error creating item:" + browser.runtime.lastError);
  } else {
    console.log("item created successfully");
  }
}

console.log("Test!");
```

The issue here is that I do not get any console logs beyond the initial "Plugin loaded!" and also do not get my contextmenuitem.

Comment: When debugging my plug-in,  I get `browser.contextMenus is undefined`. Also using `chrome.contextMenus` gives the same issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `contextMenus` API is only available in background scripts, not in content scripts.  This is documented here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#WebExtension_APIs

See this page for a broader overview of webextensions:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension